# How to Request Entries Automatically in x Seconds Intervals

Tags: sapui5

In an XML view, I present a `sap.m.Table` with entries from an output ODataModel. Now the first 8 entries should be output for about 5 seconds and the remaining entries automatically reload, and switch in 5 second intervals, like a dashboard.

Here is an example: I have `30` entries.

1. At the beginning → Show entries `1` to `8`.
2. After 5 seconds → Show entries `9` to `16`.
3. After next 5 seconds → Show `17` to `24`.
4. After next 5 seconds → Show `25` to `30`.
5. Then repeat from the beginning.

Would you have any idea how I can do that? Could it possibly realized on the routing function with transfer of the required parameters to the URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the cells of a table in an interval time using OData model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69379449/change-the-cells-of-a-table-in-an-interval-time-using-odata-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a Plunker to demonstrate how this can be achieved: [Plunker Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/ioh85m5OtPmcvPHyl3Bg/).

In a nutshell, you can leverage the `startIndex` and `length` parameters of the [ManagedObject#bindAggregation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation) method. More specifically, you use them to bind the table repeatedly.

```js
  this.byId("list").bindItems({
    path: "/Meetups",
    template: this.byId("template"),
    templateShareable: true,
    startIndex: start,
    length: SLICE_SIZE
  });
```

Because you continually rebinding the table, you can simply create the template object inside the XML view as a `dependent`, then you can access it via `this.byId(...)`. We need to use the `templateShareable` flag to indicate that the template will be reused in further bindings (on the next tick).

```xml
<dependents>
  <StandardListItem id="template" title="{Title}" 
    description="{Description}" counter="{MeetupID}" />
</dependents>
```

Regarding the routing, I made two routes: one initial ("default") route and one route which specifies the start index ("withStart"). Both of them pointing of course to the same view.

```js
  "routes": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "name": "default",
    "target": "main"
  }, {
    "pattern": "/{start}",
    "name": "withStart",
    "target": "main"
  }]
```

The transition between "slices" is done with the help of [jQuery.sap.delayedCall](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.delayedCall). You can also use a [IntervalTrigger](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger/overview) instead, but it might cause some problems if the view is not the first one shown (as the first "slice" might not be shown for the full 5 seconds, depending of course on how you implement it).

```js
jQuery.sap.delayedCall(INTERVAL, this, this.onTick, [start]);
```

Then a tick happens (i.e. when we need to change the "slice"), we simply do a navigation to the `withStart` route and increment the `start` index parameter. At this point, we can also check if we need to start from zero again (if the start index is greater than the total count).

```js
  start += SLICE_SIZE;
  if (this.count && start >= this.count) {
    start = 0;
  }
  this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("withStart", {start: start});
```

In order to find out the total count (to be able to determine if you should go to zero), you can use the information from the List / Table's [ListBinding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding).

```js
    var oBinding = this.byId("list").getBinding("items");
    if (oBinding.isLengthFinal()) {
      this.count = oBinding.getLength();
    }
```

One problem that you might face in a multi-view application is that, if the user navigates between your "dashboard" view and some other view, the `delayedCall` might cause you to navigate back again to the "dashboard" view (i.e. the user might get "trapped" in the dashboard). To circumvent this, you could check to see if the view is visible first, before doing the `navTo` call.

---

## Later edit:

For improving performance due to loading times you can use two different approaches:

1. Use the [operation mode](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode) parameter when you are doing the binding. Setting it to `Client` will load all entries at once on the client side and the pagination mechanism will be done without further requests (at least in theory).

```js
  this.byId("list").bindItems({
    path: "/Meetups",
    template: this.byId("template"),
    templateShareable: true,
    startIndex: start,
    length: SLICE_SIZE,
    operationMode: OperationMode.Client
  });
```

2. Do an initial load of the data using the [ODataModel.read](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/read) method, store the results into a JSON Model and then use the JSON Model for binding the list instead of the OData Model.

```js
var oModel = this.getView().getModel("myJsonModel");
this.getView().getModel().read("/Meetups", {
    success: function(oData) {
        oModel.setData(oData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Serban, 
Thank you for you fast answer. I will then implement your solution proposal. Have a nice evening ;-)

Comment: The solution works great. However, I have the problem that the data is loaded for a very long time  when changing the page (busy loading). I have an ODATA data connection to an SAP backend system.
Is there any way to pre-load the data before it is displayed, just to not display that busy loading to the user.
I would be very happy to receive an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have enhanced the answer to also reflect this question. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you Serban. That seems like a good solution. Nevertheless, the data that I load from the SAP backend system must always be up to date, because the datas change after a certain amount of time (for example, the status, progress...).
Is it possible to extend the function so that the data is updated once per 5 minutes and then stored in a model for these 5 minutes and then output? Once per 5 minutes the busy loading is acceptable ;-)

By the way, thank you for your competent help :-) 

Greetings O. Becker

Comment: In that case, if you use version one you can do a model.refresh method call on the OData model periodically; if you use the second version, you simply have to periodically do the read + store into the JSON Model. For calling something periodically you can use either the sap.ui.core.IntervalTrigger object or the jQuery.sap.intervalCall function.