# Change the cells of a table in an interval time using OData model

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, settimeout, intervals

I have this code and I need my table to show the first 10 patients and, after 10 seconds, show the next 10 without touching any button (automatically).

I'm looking for something similar to this: https://embed.plnkr.co/ioh85m5OtPmcvPHyl3Bg/

But with an OData model (as specified on my view and controller).

This is my view:

```xml
<Table id="tablaPacientes" items="{/EspCoSet}">
  <columns>
    <!-- ... -->
  </columns>
  <ColumnListItem>
    <ObjectIdentifier title="{Bett}" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

This is my controller:

```js
onInit: function () {
  var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("zctv");
  this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},

onBeforeRendering: function () { // method to get the local IP because I need it for the OData
  var ipAddress;
  var RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection;
  var self = this;

  function grepSDP (sdp) {
    var ip = /(192\.168\.(0|\d{0,3})\.(0|\d{0,3}))/i;
    sdp.split('\r\n').forEach(function (line) {
      if (line.match(ip)) {
        ipAddress = line.match(ip)[0];
        self.setIp(ipAddress);
      }
    });
  }

  if (RTCPeerConnection) {
    (function () {
      var rtc = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
      });
      rtc.createDataChannel('', {
        reliable: false
      });
      rtc.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
        if (evt.candidate) {
          grepSDP(evt.candidate.candidate);
        }
      };
      rtc.createOffer(function (offerDesc) {
        rtc.setLocalDescription(offerDesc);
      }, function (e) {
        console.log("Failed to get Ip address");
      });
    })();
  }
},

setIp: function (ip) {
  this.getView().byId("planta").bindElement({
    path: "/CenTVSet('" + ip + "')"
  });
  var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
  var that = this;
  oModel.read("/CenTVSet('" + ip + "')", {
    success: function (oData, oRes) {
      var einri = oData.Einri;
      var orgpf = oData.Orgpf;
      var oTable = that.getView().byId("tablaPacientes");
      var oBinding = oTable.getBinding("items");
      var aFilters = [];
      var filterO = new Filter("Orgna", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, orgpf);
      aFilters.push(filterO);
      var filterE = new Filter("Einri", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, einri);
      aFilters.push(filterE);
      oBinding.filter(aFilters);
    }
  });
}
```

I searched some functions like `IntervalTrigger` but I really don't know how can I use it for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some small samples:

- OData V4: [https://embed.plnkr.co/4zIAH7q2E0lngbyX](https://embed.plnkr.co/4zIAH7q2E0lngbyX?show=controller%2FRoot.controller.js,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)
- OData V2: [https://embed.plnkr.co/rNa0TktXiQqSCGJV](https://embed.plnkr.co/rNa0TktXiQqSCGJV?show=controller%2FRoot.controller.js,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)

> ```js
> startList: function(listBase, $skip, $top, restInfo) {
>   let startIndex = $skip;
>   let length = $top;
>   let totalSize;
>   (function repeat(that) {
>     const bindingInfo = Object.assign({ startIndex, length }, restInfo);
>     listBase.bindItems(bindingInfo);
>     listBase.data("repeater", event => {
>       totalSize = event.getParameter("total"); // $count value
>       startIndex += $top;
>       startIndex = startIndex < totalSize ? startIndex : 0;
>       setTimeout(() => repeat(that), 2000);
>     }).attachEventOnce("updateFinished", listBase.data("repeater"), that);
>   })(this);
> },
>
> stopList: function(listBase) {
>   listBase.detachEvent("updateFinished", listBase.data("repeater"), this);
> },
> ```

The samples make use of `startIndex` and `length` in the list binding info which translates to `$skip` and `$top` system queries of the entity request URL. I.e. appending those system queries to the request URL (e.g. `https://<host>/<service>/<EntitySet>?$skip=3&$top=3`), should return the correct set of entities [like this](https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZPDCDS_SRV/SEPMRA_I_Product_E?$format=json&$skip=3&$top=3).

Additional options for the list binding info can be found in the UI5 documentation as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59158697/5846045).

### JavaScript part

The interval is implemented with an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) in combination with `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

`setInterval` has the following disadvantages:

- The callback is not immediately invoked. You'd have to wait 10 seconds first to trigger the 1st callback.
- Does not wait for the data response to arrive. This may cause skipping a batch or showing it for a too short period of time because the delay simply continues regardless of the server response.

`setTimeout` instead offers a better control when the next batch should be requested.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could bind you items using bindItems, pass skip,top parameters and wrap the whole thing in a setInterval

```
var iSkip = 0;
var iTop = 10;
setInterval(function() {

    table.bindItems("/EspCoSet", {
        urlParameters: {
            "$skip": iSkip.toString() // Get first 10 entries
            "$top": iTop.toString()
        },
        success: fuction (oData) {
            iSkip = iTop; // Update iSkip and iTop to get the next set
            iTop+= 10;
        }
        ...
    }, 10000); // Each 10 seconds
)
```

2. Almost the same thing, just use oModel.read to read the entities into you viewModel.allEntities, bind your table to the viewModel.shownEntities and use a setInterval to get the next 10 from allEntities to update shownEntities.

Comment: The `bindItems` is incorrectly used as pointed out at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436193/5846045. We can't use the same option from `v2.ODataModel.read()` in `bindItems`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I messed up, wrote it out of my head, mixed .read and .bindItems up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69450079/5846045 might be more helpful